# aligning side by side listed items li

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i have this behavior always happening when i try to align the li beside each others i get a gap in the third or fourth row. I actually don't understand why.

[image]

this is an example of what i always get.

this is part of my code . the ul and li :

```
li.product {
        width: 9.043478% !important;
        float: left;
        margin: 2% !important;
    }
ul.products {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`

Comment: Check updated answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` to get it.

Below is working example.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
  <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height to li's to prevent them from looking that way.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of height of your images is not equal try putting height to image and see. if you set height of all image to same it will work.

```
li img {
    height: 200px;
}
```